# html button not inheriting font-size (css)

Tags: html, css

I'm sure it is meant to be like this (e.g. not a bug or browser flaw), but is it correct that the button text does not use the font size declared higher up?

```
<div style="font-size:10px;">

    This text would be 10px sized

    <div>
       This text would be 10px sized
    </div>

    <input type="button" value="OK" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The button is supposed to match the OS's style unless you *explicitly* style it using CSS.

Comment: haha...  if I run Safari on my PC, it still looks like a Mac button!  :)

Comment: @Michael Bray - Well, nothing else in Safari for Windows looks like native Windows either... ;P

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it on my end on Chrome, FF, and IE unless you define the button itself, it will maintain the default size.